# KVM/Qemu Guest Shutdown problems

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, centos6, qemu

on both host and guest running CentOS 6.3 with KVM/Qemu virtualization, I have the following scenarios:

1. "virsh shutdown kvm1" did not shutdown at all. virsh lists guest as running.
2. "service libvirt-guests stop" did not shutdown in 280 seconds (shutdown_timeout=300. on_shutdown=shutdown)
3. "shutdown now" from within guest, guest becomes unreachable. virsh lists guest as running, though it could not connect to it.
4. "shutdown -h now" from within guest works.
5. "shutdown -r now" from within guest works.

Libvirt logs show nothing for the first 3 scenarios. I can pause the guest fine.

Grub doesnt have acpi=off. ACPI was installed after the reply by @mgorven below. There is nothing on guest logs regarding ACPI aside from [these entries](http://pastebin.com/QU9hNm9N) from /var/log/messages. It is puzzling to me that there are entries regarding ACPI since it was not installed up until the last line of the log.

**Bottom line, I cannot shutdown from outside the guest. What do I check to figure out what is going on?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that `acpid` is running inside the guests. If it isn't you need to install the `acpid` package. This is what receives the ACPI power button signal from KVM and causes the guest to shut itself down.

Comment: installed now. i will report back with the results when I can test it. thanks.

Comment: "virsh shutdown domain" did nothing with acpi installed on the guest domain.

Comment: grub doesnt have acpi=off, but could this be because of a modified kernel? Its Atomic Rocket Turtle

Comment: @Gaia What on earth is an Atomic Rocket Turtle? I would always suspect strangeness in a niche distribution like that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, sorry I mean ASL by www.atomicorp.com (ART is their repo)

Comment: Have you made sure the `acpid` daemon is actually running after installing the package?

Comment: @daffI did, I restarted the guest after installing the package and things work fine (virsh is able to shutdown). what I don't understand is all the ACPI messages in the log (see OP) before ACPI was installed, but that doesnt matter much...

Comment: Note for Debian users: if you disabled installation of _Recommended_ packages, then `acpid` alone does not much because it only contains the binaries. You need to install `acpi-support-base` package to handle power button ACPI events. For Ubuntu, `acpid` contains both binaries and base event handlers and is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

For CentOS.6.3 this worked well:

```
# yum -y install acpid; /etc/init.d/acpid start; chkconfig --level 235 acpid on;
```